# Extracting sentences around a string

Tags: php, regex

I've been learning how to use regex for a little while now, and I thought it would be a great Idea to start on searching a Wikipedia page for sentences containing $search.

So far, I managed to figure out the getting sentences half of it, but I'm just wondering how to get only the sentences with $search in them too.

```
$content = $wdata->query->pages->$wpageid->extract; 
preg_match_all('/(?<=[.?!]|^).*?(?=([.?!])\s{0,3}[A-Z]|$)/s',$content,$matches);
echo "<pre>";
for($i=0;$i<count($matches[0]);$i++)
$result[] = trim($matches[0][$i]).$matches[1][$i];
print_r($result);
```

So far this is what I have, which works well at getting an array of sentences, but no all are related to, or fit the $search term.

I was wondering how I can check or only get the sentences with $search in them.

It should be a simple as pasting `('.$search.')` in the regex `/(?<=[.?!]|^).*?(?=([.?!])\s{0,3}[A-Z]|$)/s` but, as I said, I'm new to regex, and I don't know where to put it, and even if that would work.

Any help from you guys would be much appreciated!

**Edit:**
Also, if its not too much trouble, the Wikipedia sections stay, and for some reason, some lines aren't part of the array (see photo).
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a list of sentences, use your FOR loop to filter only the relevant ones with, ie, stripos() function. You don't really need to put your $search inside the regex.

EDIT, example:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($matches[0]);$i++)
{
    $sentence = trim($matches[0][$i]).$matches[1][$i];

    if (stripos($sentence, $search) !== false)
        $result[] = $sentence;
}
```

Comment: Yes It Does work, thankyou so much :)  That has been bugging me all afternoon

Comment: In addition, you should be careful with inserting your search string inside the regex, as it may contain characters with specific meaning to the expression language.

Comment: Yeah, like the $... and any character it doesn't like. This is why I'm lost when it comes to regex...

Comment: preg_quote()? What does this do?

Comment: If its not too much trouble, could you look at my edit in the original question when you get a chance @Kiko? Thanks again

Comment: preg_quote fixes your string so it can be inserted into the expression, if you want to do it like that.

Comment: oh, well I'll keep it in mind, but, for now its working with your method, which seems more correct

Comment: About the additional EDIT in the question: I'd have to know what's in the $content to check.

Comment: a wikipedia article in plain text, maybe, before preg_match, we could remove the === in the text, which would make the section names incorrect sentences, therefore, not displayed

Comment: wikipedia url, sample search is google: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=google&format=json&explaintext&redirects&inprop=url&indexpageids

Comment: As I am not really sure what your regex does, I'd remove ==something== with **$content = preg_replace('/={2,}.+?={2,}/', '', $content);** before the expression and, inside regex, I would replace {0,3} with *

Comment: Yep, that fixed the ==Thing==, however, there are still stray sentences like the one with the arrow pointing to it, its not needed, but if you can figure it out, that'd be nice :)

Comment: ok, i figured that the gaps are because the sentence before end in a quote (."), but again, i'm not sure how to ask it to check for a quote and a full stop on the end, simply changing the ([.?!]) changes all sorts of stuff, for some reason, so... how could I go about this